# OpenCV-iOS demos run at 6-10 FPS on iPad, is this normal?

Tags: ios, opencv

The OpenCV-iOS detection and tracking code runs betwee 6-10 FPS on my iPad.

Is this normal?

I figured their "sample" code would run as fast as it could...

```
DetectTrackSample.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "DetectTrackSample.h"
#include "ObjectTrackingClass.h"
#include "FeatureDetectionClass.h"
#include "Globals.h"

DetectTrackSample::DetectTrackSample()
: m_fdAlgorithmName("ORB")
, m_feAlgorithmName("FREAK")
, m_maxCorners(200)
, m_hessianThreshold(400)
, m_nFeatures(500)
, m_minMatches(4)
, m_drawMatches(true)
, m_drawPerspective(true)
{

    std::vector<std::string> fdAlgos, feAlgos, otAlgos;
    // feature detection options
    fdAlgos.push_back("ORB");
    fdAlgos.push_back("SURF");
    registerOption("Detector",       "", &m_fdAlgorithmName, fdAlgos);

    // feature extraction options
    feAlgos.push_back("ORB");
    feAlgos.push_back("SURF");
    feAlgos.push_back("FREAK");
    registerOption("Extractor",       "", &m_feAlgorithmName, feAlgos);

    // SURF feature detector options
    registerOption("hessianThreshold", "SURF", &m_hessianThreshold, 300, 500);

    // ORB feature detector options
    registerOption("nFeatures", "ORB", &m_nFeatures, 0, 1500);

    // matcher options
    registerOption("Minumum matches", "Matcher", &m_minMatches, 4, 200);

    // object tracking options
    registerOption("m_maxCorners", "Tracking", &m_maxCorners, 0, 1000);

    // Display options
    registerOption("Matches", "Draw", &m_drawMatches);
    registerOption("Perspective", "Draw", &m_drawPerspective);
}

//! Gets a sample name
std::string DetectTrackSample::getName() const
{
    return "Detection and Tracking";
}

std::string DetectTrackSample::getSampleIcon() const
{
    return "DetectTrackSampleIcon.png";
}

//! Returns a detailed sample description
std::string DetectTrackSample::getDescription() const
{
    return "Combined feature detection and object tracking sample.";
}

//! Returns true if this sample requires setting a reference image for latter use
bool DetectTrackSample::isReferenceFrameRequired() const
{
    return true;
}

//! Sets the reference frame for latter processing
void DetectTrackSample::setReferenceFrame(const cv::Mat& reference)
{
    getGray(reference, objectImage);
    computeObject = true;
}

// Reset object keypoints and descriptors
void DetectTrackSample::resetReferenceFrame() const
{
    detectObject = false;
    computeObject = false;
    trackObject = false;
}

//! Processes a frame and returns output image 
bool DetectTrackSample::processFrame(const cv::Mat& inputFrame, cv::Mat& outputFrame)
{
    // display the frame
    inputFrame.copyTo(outputFrame);

    // convert input frame to gray scale
    getGray(inputFrame, imageNext);

    // begin tracking object
    if ( trackObject ) {
        // prepare the tracking class
        ObjectTrackingClass tracker;
        tracker.setMaxCorners(m_maxCorners);

        // track object
        tracker.track(outputFrame,
                 imagePrev,
                 imageNext,
                 pointsPrev,
                 pointsNext,
                 status,
                 err);

        // check if the next points array isn't empty
        if ( pointsNext.empty() ) {
            // if it is, go back to detect
            trackObject = false;
            detectObject = true;
        }
    }

    // try to find the object in the scene
    if (detectObject) {

        // prepare the robust matcher and set paremeters
        FeatureDetectionClass rmatcher;
        rmatcher.setConfidenceLevel(0.98);
        rmatcher.setMinDistanceToEpipolar(1.0);
        rmatcher.setRatio(0.65f);

        // feature detector setup
        if (m_fdAlgorithmName == "SURF")
        {
            // prepare keypoints detector
            cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = new cv::SurfFeatureDetector(m_hessianThreshold);
            rmatcher.setFeatureDetector(detector);
        }
        else if (m_fdAlgorithmName == "ORB")
        {
            // prepare feature detector and detect the object keypoints
            cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = new cv::OrbFeatureDetector(m_nFeatures);
            rmatcher.setFeatureDetector(detector);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Unsupported algorithm:" << m_fdAlgorithmName << std::endl;
            assert(false);
        }

        // feature extractor and matcher setup
        if (m_feAlgorithmName == "SURF")
        {
            // prepare feature extractor
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor;
            rmatcher.setDescriptorExtractor(extractor);
            // prepare the appropriate matcher for SURF 
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher = new cv::BFMatcher(cv::NORM_L2, false);
            rmatcher.setDescriptorMatcher(matcher);

        } else if (m_feAlgorithmName == "ORB")
        {
            // prepare feature extractor
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::OrbDescriptorExtractor;
            rmatcher.setDescriptorExtractor(extractor);
            // prepare the appropriate matcher for ORB
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher = new cv::BFMatcher(cv::NORM_HAMMING, false);
            rmatcher.setDescriptorMatcher(matcher);

        } else if (m_feAlgorithmName == "FREAK")
        {
            // prepare feature extractor
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::FREAK;
            rmatcher.setDescriptorExtractor(extractor);
            // prepare the appropriate matcher for FREAK
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher = new cv::BFMatcher(cv::NORM_HAMMING, false);
            rmatcher.setDescriptorMatcher(matcher);
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Unsupported algorithm:" << m_feAlgorithmName << std::endl;
            assert(false);
        }

        // call the RobustMatcher to match the object keypoints with the scene keypoints
        cv::vector<cv::Point2f> objectKeypoints2f, sceneKeypoints2f;
        std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
        cv::Mat fundamentalMat = rmatcher.match(imageNext, // input scene image
                                                objectKeypoints, // input computed object image keypoints
                                                objectDescriptors, // input computed object image descriptors
                                                matches, // output matches
                                                objectKeypoints2f, // output object keypoints (Point2f)
                                                sceneKeypoints2f); // output scene keypoints (Point2f)

        if ( matches.size() >= m_minMatches ) { // assume something was detected

            // draw perspetcive lines (box object in the frame)
            if (m_drawPerspective)
                rmatcher.drawPerspective(outputFrame,
                                         objectImage,
                                         objectKeypoints2f,
                                         sceneKeypoints2f);

            // draw keypoint matches as yellow points on the output frame
            if (m_drawMatches)
                rmatcher.drawMatches(outputFrame,
                                     matches,
                                     sceneKeypoints2f);

            // init points array for tracking
            pointsNext = sceneKeypoints2f;

            // set flags
            detectObject = false;
            trackObject = true;
        }
    }

    // compute object image keypoints and descriptors
    if (computeObject) {

        // select feature detection mechanism
        if ( m_fdAlgorithmName == "SURF" )
        {
            // prepare keypoints detector
            cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = new cv::SurfFeatureDetector(m_hessianThreshold);
            // Compute object keypoints
            detector->detect(objectImage,objectKeypoints);

        }
        else if ( m_fdAlgorithmName == "ORB" )
        {
            // prepare feature detector and detect the object keypoints
            cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = new cv::OrbFeatureDetector(m_nFeatures);
            // Compute object keypoints
            detector->detect(objectImage,objectKeypoints);
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Unsupported algorithm:" << m_fdAlgorithmName << std::endl;
            assert(false);
        }

        // select feature extraction mechanism
        if ( m_feAlgorithmName == "SURF" )
        {
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor;
            // Compute object feature descriptors
            extractor->compute(objectImage,objectKeypoints,objectDescriptors);
        }
        else if ( m_feAlgorithmName == "ORB" )
        {
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::OrbDescriptorExtractor;
            // Compute object feature descriptors
            extractor->compute(objectImage,objectKeypoints,objectDescriptors);
        }
        else if ( m_feAlgorithmName == "FREAK" )
        {
            cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::FREAK;
            // Compute object feature descriptors
            extractor->compute(objectImage,objectKeypoints,objectDescriptors);
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Unsupported algorithm:" << m_feAlgorithmName << std::endl;
            assert(false);
        }

        // set flags
        computeObject = false;
        detectObject = true;        
    }

    // backup previous frame
    imageNext.copyTo(imagePrev);

    // backup points array
    std::swap(pointsNext, pointsPrev);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What resolution are you filming and can you post some code?

Comment: By the looks of it, around 500x500. Is that too much?

Comment: That depends on the detection and tracking code. Can you post some code?

Comment: Added a file to the OP

Comment: What objects can be tracked with this code? Can you share a link of the source? *Update: Is it right that you can detect a picture for e.g. a Coca Cola logo in a (video)frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be normal. It depends on your detection and tracking code.

For example:

> On an iPhone 4 using the CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT option the demo
>   app achieves up to **4 fps** when a face is in the frame. This drops to
>   around **1.5 fps** when no face is present. Without the
>   CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT option multiple faces can be detected in a
>   frame at around **1.8 fps**. Note that the live video preview always runs
>   at the full **30 fps** irrespective of the processing frame rate and
>   processFrame:videoRect:videoOrientation: is called at **30 fps** if you
>   only perform minimal processing.

**Source:** [Click](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/face-tracking/)